# Select all with latest timestamp in django?

Tags: python, mysql, django

This seems like it should be obvious but I can't get it to work.

I'm using django to query a simple table into which a bunch of data gets inserted periodically. I'd like to write a view that only pulls data with the latest timestamp, something like

```
select * from mytable
where event_time = (
    select max(event_time) from mytable);
```

What's the proper syntax for that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try with `latest` method. Here [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#latest)

```
MyModel.objects.latest('event_time')
```

assuming `event_time` has a date value, this will return the latest object (the max date)

Comment: +1 for this answer, the only stupid thing is that if there's no entries Django raises an exception which is very annoying.

Comment: Django should handle it, considering it is an built-in function.

Comment: test it and see, on 1.6 it definitely raises an exception

Comment: _Note that earliest() and latest() exist purely for convenience and readability._ It is basicly a `get()` method that raises a `DoesNotExist` exception. You are right, it is annoying.

Comment: I just tried it, and I'm still doing something wrong. I have a mysql table with a timestamp column "event_time". I have a model that points to the table, which reads it as `event_time = models.DateTimeField()`. In my view, I run `response_data = darLog.objects.latest('event_time')`, but it throws an error that the darLog object is not iterable. If I do instead darLog.objects.all() it works fine. What am I missing?

Comment: Oh, I guess you are trying to iterate over the result queryset. Keep this in mind: `Model.objects.all()` will return a 'list' of objects, and `Model.objects.latest('event_time')` will return **one** object which is not iterable because it is just one.

Comment: I just found that through the interactive shell, even though there are several objects with the 'latest' timestamps it just seems to pick one. I guess I need a more precise query then.

Comment: `latest` will always return **only one** object. If you need to pick more than one object with **the same timestamp** you need to use `filter()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:
Assuming your table name is EventTime

```
EventTime.objects.all().order_by('-timestamp')[0]
```

`[0]` at the end will give you the first result. 
Remove it and you will have all entries order by timestamp in desc order

**EDIT:** 
A better approach suggested by @Gocht will be:

```
EventTime.objects.all().order_by('-timestamp').first()
```

This will handle the scenario when there is no object present in the database.

Comment: I think `EventTime.objects.all().order_by('-timestamp').first()` is a better code.

Comment: You can also use .last()